# Copied project folder, react-native project will not archive

Tags: xcode, react-native

I copied my entire project folder to a new folder (noob mistake, I know). However, I've been able to get everything up and running until now. I have run the app on my device, on the emulator and it all works. However, when trying to archive the project (Xcode => Product => Archive) I get an error during the 'Run custom shell script 'Bundle React Native code and images' because something is still referring to my old folder.

```
module.js:540
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/[me]/[folder]/[old project folder name]'
```

I've searched my entire project for requires out to my old folder but cannot find any. Is there some place where this would be cached that I can change? The script throwing the error is in 'node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh'.

There are a bunch of variables in that file like "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH" or "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"

could one of these be the issue? If so, can I change it into a hard-coded path, or is there some place where I can change this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing npm modules and re-installing them.

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work! I just ended up re-initializing the project in a new folder and bringing over the code. Not sure what the error was, but thanks for the help :)